# window.btoa(); in javascript safe/secure?

Tags: javascript, encryption

Hello I am a JavaScript noob, I was wondering if `window.btoa();` in JavaScript secure?
I cannot seem to find a good encryption program in JavaScript so i would like to use this function built into JavaScript

Comment: What are you trying to encrypt?

For 99.99% of the cases, browser-based encryption is a Bad Idea for multiple reasons.

If you explain why you are trying to encrypt and why, perhaps we can suggest a better approach.

Comment: `btoa ()` is not an encryption tool. In that regard it is not secure in any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've heard good things about bcrypt.  Check it out https://code.google.com/p/javascript-bcrypt/